# Remove a realtime listener on firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, listener, real-time-updates

I am kinda new on firebase and I don't quite understand how to detach a realtime listener. I already read the official documentation but still don't understand how to. If anyone could simplify it for me and create a function to start the listener and another one to stop it, it would be really awesome.

To start the listener I need just to call **start()**

```
function start(){
  firebase.firestore().doc("users/x").onSnapshot(function(doc) {
   console.log(doc.data());
  });
}
```

But to stop the listener I tried to call the function with noting in it, however it doesn't work

```
//Doesn't work
function stop(){
 firebase.firestore().doc("users/x").onSnapshot(function(doc) {
   //Not putting anything in here
  });
 }
```

Comment: just directly acess the data from firestore dont use onsnapshot listner https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data check get data section

Comment: I know how to do that, but I require a realtime listener in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
var fbListener = null;

function start(){
  fbListener = firebase.firestore().doc("users/x").onSnapshot(function(doc) {
   console.log(doc.data());
  });
}

function stop(){
  fbListener();
}
```

Have a look at the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#returns-=-void): `onSnapshot` returns "an unsubscribe function that can be called to cancel the snapshot listener".